# Asymptotic behaviour and bound for function

Tags: analysis, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

Suppose we have a continuous postive function $f(t)$ (if you need some extra regularity, you can assume it) such that $f$ is non decrasing, so for all $t_2 > t_1$ we have
\begin{align*}
f(t_2) \geq f(t_1)
\end{align*}
and we also know the asymptotic behaviour, in particular
\begin{align*}
f(t) \sim t \quad t \to +\infty
\end{align*}
so we can say that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to +\infty} \frac{f(t)}{t}=c
\end{align*}
where $c>0$ is a positive constant. Now we want to find a bound for $f(t)$, for example we can say that $\exists M>0$ such that
\begin{align*}
f(t) \leq M t \quad \forall t
\end{align*}
or we can find another bound for $f(t)$ such that $f(t) \leq ... t ...$ for all t? Do you have any ideas for a bound for $f(t)$ ? Thanks

Comment: $f(t)\sim t$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$ means that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}=1$. Thus, there is $a>0$ such that for $t\geq a$, $\Big|\frac{f(t)}{t}-1\Big|<\frac12$. That is $\frac{1}{2}t< f(t)<\frac32 t$ for all $t\geq a$. For *small* values of $t$ one cannot say anything for general $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a $t_0$ such that $f(t) \leq (c+1) t$ for $t \geq t_0$. But your inequality need not hold for $t$ near $0$: Take $f(x)=\sqrt x$ for $0 <x<1$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x \geq 1$.